# Problems with object in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem trying to create a Shiny app. With this table:

```
data <- data.frame(
  variable1 = c('S','S','S','N','N','N'),
  variable2 = c('S','S','N','N','N','N'),
  TYPE = c('REAL','ESTUDIO','REAL','ESTUDIO','REAL','ESTUDIO')
  )
```

UI:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "variable", 
              label = "Variable:",
              choices = c("variable1","variable2"), 
              selected = "variable1"),

  selectInput(inputId = "medida", 
              label = "Medida:",
              choices = c("Mix","Freq"), 
              selected = "Mix"),

  plotOutput("plot"))
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  dateRangeInput<-reactive({
    dataset = data %>%
      group_by(variable1,TYPE) %>%
      summarise(Freq=n()) %>%
      inner_join(data %>%
                   group_by(TYPE) %>%
                   summarise(Freq_Tot=n())
                 ,
                 by="TYPE") %>%
      mutate(Mix=Freq/Freq_Tot)
    dataset
  })

  output$plot <-renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=dateRangeInput(), 
           aes_string(x=input$variable,
                      y=input$medida,
                      fill="TYPE")) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",
               position="dodge")
  })

}
```

It works fine (I assume that is not the best R code of history, I am just learning), and if I run the final code:

```
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Results:

[image: Results]

As you can see I made a simple app (I am just starting), so I wanted to have the graph with the variable that I choose in the UI. So when I make these changes:

- In the server code, when I define dateRangeInput I used in the group by the variable "variable1".
- Now I put input$variable instead.

  ```
  dateRangeInput<-reactive({
    dataset = data %>%
      group_by(input$variable,TYPE) %>%
      summarise(Freq=n()) %>%
      inner_join(data %>%
                   group_by(TYPE) %>%
                   summarise(Freq_Tot=n())
                 ,
                 by="TYPE") %>%
      mutate(Mix=Freq/Freq_Tot)
    dataset
  })
  ```

It results in this error:

[image: error]

I think that the code is not understanding the output as a variable. I tried to fix it with switch function, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you want to filter by input$variable rather than group by it. I'll add an answer in a moment

Comment: Ah, but I now see what you want. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, the issue seems to be the original counting of the variables. That's because your code above only considers variable1 not both variables, meaning that the shiny app will error if asked for variable 2.

When building a shiny app for non-big data, I usually create a script to do as much as I can without reactive elements. In this case, this would give me the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
    variable1 = c('S','S','S','N','N','N'),
    variable2 = c('S','S','N','N','N','N'),
    TYPE = c('REAL','ESTUDIO','REAL','ESTUDIO','REAL','ESTUDIO')
)

data1 <- data %>% 
    transmute_all(as_factor)

data_tidy <- data1 %>% 
    gather(
        key = "Variable", 
        value = "value", 
        -TYPE
        )
```

... which generates:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   TYPE    Variable  value
   <fct>   <chr>     <chr>
 1 REAL    variable1 S    
 2 ESTUDIO variable1 S    
 3 REAL    variable1 S    
 4 ESTUDIO variable1 N    
 5 REAL    variable1 N    
 6 ESTUDIO variable1 N    
 7 REAL    variable2 S    
 8 ESTUDIO variable2 S    
 9 REAL    variable2 N    
10 ESTUDIO variable2 N    
11 REAL    variable2 N    
12 ESTUDIO variable2 N
```

We can then summarise this data:

```
data_summary_Freq <- data_tidy %>% 
    count(TYPE, Variable, value, name = "Freq")

data_summary_Total <- data_summary_Freq %>% 
    group_by(Variable, TYPE) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(Freq))

data_summary <- data_summary_Freq %>% 
    left_join(
        data_summary_Total, 
        by = c("Variable", "TYPE")
        ) %>% 
    mutate(Mix = Freq / total) %>% 
    gather("Output", "Number", -TYPE, -Variable, -value, -total)
```

... and that generates the following results for `data_summary`:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 6
   TYPE    Variable  value total Output Number
   <fct>   <chr>     <chr> <int> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 REAL    variable1 N         3 Freq    1    
 2 REAL    variable1 S         3 Freq    2    
 3 REAL    variable2 N         3 Freq    2    
 4 REAL    variable2 S         3 Freq    1    
 5 ESTUDIO variable1 N         3 Freq    2    
 6 ESTUDIO variable1 S         3 Freq    1    
 7 ESTUDIO variable2 N         3 Freq    2    
 8 ESTUDIO variable2 S         3 Freq    1    
 9 REAL    variable1 N         3 Mix     0.333
10 REAL    variable1 S         3 Mix     0.667
11 REAL    variable2 N         3 Mix     0.667
12 REAL    variable2 S         3 Mix     0.333
13 ESTUDIO variable1 N         3 Mix     0.667
14 ESTUDIO variable1 S         3 Mix     0.333
15 ESTUDIO variable2 N         3 Mix     0.667
16 ESTUDIO variable2 S         3 Mix     0.333
```

The remaining problem involves building the shiny code around this data frame.

Overall, that means:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
    variable1 = c('S','S','S','N','N','N'),
    variable2 = c('S','S','N','N','N','N'),
    TYPE = c('REAL','ESTUDIO','REAL','ESTUDIO','REAL','ESTUDIO')
)

data1 <- data %>% 
    transmute_all(as_factor)

data_tidy <- data1 %>% 
    gather(
        key = "Variable", 
        value = "value", 
        -TYPE
        )

data_summary_Freq <- data_tidy %>% 
    count(TYPE, Variable, value, name = "Freq")

data_summary_Total <- data_summary_Freq %>% 
    group_by(Variable, TYPE) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(Freq))

data_summary <- data_summary_Freq %>% 
    left_join(
        data_summary_Total, 
        by = c("Variable", "TYPE")
        ) %>% 
    mutate(Mix = Freq / total) %>% 
    gather("Output", "Number", -TYPE, -Variable, -value, -total)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "variable", 
                label = "Variable:",
                choices = c("variable1","variable2"), 
                selected = "variable1"),

    selectInput(inputId = "medida", 
                label = "Medida:",
                choices = c("Mix","Freq"), 
                selected = "Mix"),

    plotOutput("plot")
    )

server <- function(input, output) {

    dateRangeInput <- reactive({
        data_summary %>% 
            filter(
                Variable == input$variable,
                Output == input$medida
                )
    })

    output$plot <-renderPlot({
        dateRangeInput() %>% 
            ggplot() +
            geom_bar(
                aes(
                    x = value,
                    y = Number, 
                    group = TYPE,
                    fill = TYPE
                    ),
                stat = "identity",
                position = "dodge"
                ) +
            labs(
                title = paste(input$medida, "information about", input$variable)
            )
        })

}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

... which generates [this app](https://robin.shinyapps.io/mixAndType/), which I've uploaded to *shinyapps.io*.

I hope that I've understood your problem correctly and that this helps.

All the best ...

Comment: I am really grateful, it helped me a lot

Comment: Splendid. Pleased to hear it.